Error while running C++ CGI file on the Apache2 server
I created a main.cpp which is converted to song_stack.cgi and is stored in /opt/homebrew/var/www/cgi-bin
the httpd.conf file is stored in /opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
I created an index.html and stored it in the root directory of Apache: /opt/homebrew/var/www
The code is below:
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Song Stack</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Song Stack</h1>
    <form action="/cgi-bin/song_stack.cgi" method="GET">
        <label for="song">Song URL:</label>
        <input type="text" id="song" name="insert">
        <button type="submit">Add Song</button>
    </form>
    <form action="/cgi-bin/song_stack.cgi" method="GET">
        <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="1">
        <button type="submit">Delete Last Song</button>
    </form>
    <form action="/cgi-bin/song_stack.cgi" method="GET">
        <input type="hidden" name="display" value="1">
        <button type="submit">Display Songs</button>
    </form>
    <form action="/cgi-bin/song_stack.cgi" method="GET">
        <input type="hidden" name="open" value="1">
        <button type="submit">Open Last Song</button>
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>

And the main.cpp which was converted to song_stack.cgi with the command:
 g++ main.cpp -o song_stack.cgi 
 sudo mv song_stack.cgi /opt/homebrew/var/www/cgi-bin/

 chmod +x /opt/homebrew/var/www/cgi-bin/song_stack.cgi

The configurations I made in the httpd.conf file are:
# Load the cgi_module
LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so
ServerName localhost:8080

# ScriptAlias for CGI directory
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/opt/homebrew/var/www/cgi-bin/"

<Directory "/opt/homebrew/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# AddHandler for .cgi scripts
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

Then I ran:
sudo apachectl restart

after accessing http://localhost:8080/
If I give an input, it directly downloads the song_stack.cgi file

and does not display anything on the webpage.

Could you add the content of your main.cpp?

@ChristianHalaszovich I reviewed this question before it was submitted, and I explicitly asked the OP to remove main.cpp. I thought this was a configuration issue, since the CGI program doesn't get to run at all. Oh well, if you think it is relevant I'm sure it can be added back in.

@john Okay. In that case I would consider removing the c++ tag.
